# How is the standard deviation in this coin tossing experiment calculated?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, standard-deviation

I'm reading [Hypothesis Testing: The Basics](http://20bits.com/article/hypothesis-testing-the-basics), there is such an experiment:

> So, we have a coin. Our null hypothesis is that this coin is fair. We
>   flip it 100 times and it comes up heads 51 times. Do we know whether
>   the coin is biased or not?

The author mentioned Central Limit Theorem and said `the random variable is the proportion of heads in our sample of 100 coin flips. In our case, it is equal to 0.51`.

> But by the central limit theorem we also know that p approximates a
>   normal distribution. This means we can estimate the standard deviation
>   of p as
>   $$\sigma=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{N}}$$

**Why the standard deviation is calculated using this equation?** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Variance), the std of a binomial distribution is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$. What am I missing?

Comment: The binomial is a count of successes; you're not looking at the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If numerous random samples or repetitions of the same size $n$ are taken, the distribution of possible values of $\hat{p}$ is approximately a normal curve distribution with  mean $p$ and  $SD=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{N}}$. Have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221828). And, for the distinction from binomial distribution please have a [look at this thread.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156982/why-doesnt-a-sample-proportion-also-have-a-binomial-distribution)

EDIT:
To the explanation asked in the comment. $\hat{p} = X/n$, where $X$ is a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$. $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of success. We are interested in the fraction of successes.

$E(\hat{p}) = E(X/n) = np/n = p$ and $Var(\hat{p}) = Var(X/n) = Var(X)/n^2 = np(1-p)/n^2 = p(1-p)/n$. So, $SD=\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{N}}$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please explain a bit more on why there is $\frac{1}{N}$ in the SD calculation?

Comment: Edited the answer to answer this query. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The variance for the Binomial distribution is in fact equal to $np(1-p)$, however you are estimating the variance for the proportion $p$, which is a Bernoulli trial, which has variance $p(1-p)$.